# Values in my prediction changes after converting from DataFrame to CSV

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I am using the predict_proba() function to get the class probabilities. Down below are two pictures: first one is the values for the first 5 rows of the output from predict_proba() in dataframe format and the second one is after I convert the dataframe to a csv file.

Image 1
[df.head() output from Colab Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJb5B.png)

Image 2
[First 5 rows of CSV file after using to_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3g6W.png)

As it can be observed, after converting to a csv file, some of the values change. For example, from 0.365 to 365, or from 0.155 to 155. I have no idea what causes this.

I have used the same method to convert other predictions from dataframe to csv file and did not encounter such a problem before.

Comment: it looks like the width of the table is too thin, so the 0.0 or 0. is being truncated to accommodate the non-zero numbers.

Comment: **DO NOT** use images for textual data. Copy and paste the data as text into your question.